# How to remove all zeros before number in mysql query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

In one table of my database number column is below format. I have strings which looks like this one:I need to remove all zeros from starting number or starting string of the column value.

```
Approval Table in this column name is ApprovalNumber

    SNO     ApprovalNumber
    ----      -----------
    1        0007890677
    2        0090780788
    3        767078
    4        009033
    5        05097
    6        005765078
```

Here in this table I need get all records and column value before 0's should be remove while select the query result. My expected output is below

```
   SNO     ApprovalNewNo
   ----      -----------
    1        7890677
    2        90780788
    3        767078
    4        9033
    5        5097
    6        5765078
```

I tried below code but not working

```
SELECT LTRIM(ApprovalNumber,"0") AS ApprovalNewNo
FROM `ApprovalTable`
```

Can any one please help on this issue.

Comment: It helps to read the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html. `LTRIM` only removes blanks and does not accept a second parameter in MySQL. You need `TRIM` instead as shown in SelVazi's answer. And next time, please don't say "but not working", but tell us what happens technically. With your query you should get an error message. Why do you keep it a secret?

Comment: I guess the real question is: why do you store numbers as strings in your database?

Comment: On a side note: The delimiter for string literals in SQL is the single quote, not the double quote. While MySQL allows "0" under certain conditions, it can render your query invalid or lead to unexpected results with different settings. Better stick with proper single quotes hence. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/XxAG-NJ4.

Comment: Do you want the result as a character or integer data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRIM` with param `LEADING` :

```
select *, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ApprovalNumber)
from mytable
```

Because is not an *alphanumeric*, adding 0 to the `ApprovalNumber` can work:

```
select *, ApprovalNumber + 0
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ix7oL7sl)

Comment: It's working fine, Thank you from Niranjan Kumar Chowdam